# python pandas dataframe union merge list into index

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, union

I have a list of values and I want to guarantee that all values exist in the index of a data frame.

I have achieved this using the following but want to know can i do this in a simpler way? I have tried various `~ ... .isin` constructions but failed to get what I want
Thanks

```
#df1 is my data frame 
df1=pd.DataFrame({'i':[1, 3, 5, 7], 
                 'a':[2, 4, 6, 8]})
df1.set_index(['i'], inplace=True)
df1
```

[image]

```
# l is the list containing index values
# i make this a data frame with an index but no columns so i can use merge
l=[3, 4, 5]
df=pd.DataFrame(l)
df.set_index([0], inplace=True)
df.index.names=['i']
df
```

[image]

Use merge to add any missing index values

```
df1.merge(df, how='outer', on='i', sort=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reindex` together with `pd.Index.union` (assuming you don't have any duplicate values for the DataFrame index or duplicates in `l`)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'i':[1, 3, 5, 7], 'a':[2, 4, 6, 8]}).set_index('i')
l = [3, 4, 5]
```

---

```
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.union(l))
#     a
#i     
#1  2.0
#3  4.0
#4  NaN
#5  6.0
#7  8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @ALollz - panda cub here

Comment: No problem! Things can get a bit complicated if you need to deal with duplicates, because then you need to decide if you want those rows to multiplicatively grow, but if you're sure you want a non-duplicated index in the end this will work well.

Comment: i didnt know that `index.union()` could accept a list, i assumed it had to be converted to `pd.Index(l)` first. Thats good to know.

Comment: @rhug123 yup a lot of the pandas methods are fairly flexible in that they accept most array-like inputs, in this case it will accept a `list`, `set`, `np.array`, `pd.Series`, `tuple`, and a few others I'm sure Im leaving out